# Owl carousel not getting responsive

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I implemented Owl carousel code, it is working fine but i stuck on owl responsive functionality. it is not working at all.

HTML code is:

```
<div id="prd-slider" class="col-md-12" > 
       <!-- Item 1 Start -->
  <div class="item">
    <div class="Shop-Choice-sub-sec">
      <div class="Shop-Choice-border"><a href=""> <img src="http://outsource.lightspeedwl.com/marketplace/media/catalog/category/new-img-3.png" style="padding: 10px; width: 59%; margin-left: 26px;"></a> </div>
      <div class="Shop-Choice-text-section">
        <div class="col-lg-12 Shop-Choice-name">Tshirts</div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 Shop-Choice-star-img"> <img style="" src="http://outsource.lightspeedwl.com/marketplace/skin/frontend/default/emarketplace/images/star-img.png"> </div>
        <span class="Shop-Choice-prise"></span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <!-- Item 1 end -->
 <!-- Same structure for other items -->
</div>
```

css code:

```
 #prd-slider .item{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Java script code is:

```
var owl = jQuery("#prd-slider");
        owl.owlCarousel({
          autoPlay :true,
          slideSpeed : 300,
          nav : false,
          loop: true,
          items : 5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
          itemsDesktoplarg : [1000,2], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
          itemsDesktop : [700,2], 
          itemsDesktopSmall : [660,2],// betweem 900px and 601px    
          itemsTablet: [650,1], //2 items between 600 and 0
          itemsMobile : [400,1], // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
      });

    jQuery('.prev1').click(function(){
        jQuery("#prd-slider").find('.owl-prev').click();
    });

    jQuery('.next1').click(function(){
        jQuery("#prd-slider").find('.owl-next').click();
    });
```

any idea where i did mistake ...?

Comment: Can you share your CSS code ??

Comment: I edited my question. You can see my css code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, issue only with version. I used 2.0 (new version) but owl responsive was not working. Now when i replaced with 1.3 then it it working.